# Inexplicable WPF Binding Error. Source Property Not Updating

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, telerik

I am using a RadListBox in MVVM to do drag and drop between two RadListBox's. Each of them hold a ObservableCollection where ApplicationPermission implements INotifyPropertyChanged. The DataContext is the view model.

```
public class PermissionPortfolio : INotifyPropertyChanged, IEquatable<PermissionPortfolio>
{
    private string _systemId;
    private string _shortName;
    private string _accessType;
    private decimal _accountId;
    private string _longName;


    public string LongName
    {
        get { return _longName; }
        set
        {
            _longName = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string SystemId
    {
        get { return _systemId; }
        set
        {
            _systemId = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string ShortName
    {
        get { return _shortName; }
        set
        {
            _shortName = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string AccessType
    {
        get { return _accessType; }
        set
        {
            _accessType = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public decimal AccountId
    {
        get { return _accountId; }
        set
        {
            _accountId = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(PermissionPortfolio other)
    {
        return other.ShortName.Equals(ShortName) &&
               other.SystemId.Equals(SystemId) && other.AccountId == AccountId;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I've made a custom ListBoxDragDropBehavior which will handle the drops into the second list box:

```
public class UserPortfolioListBoxDragDropBehavior : ListBoxDragDropBehavior
{
    public override void Drop(DragDropState state)
    {
        if (state.IsSameControl) return;
        foreach (PermissionPortfolio portfolio in state.DraggedItems)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(portfolio.AccessType))
            {
                AccessTypeDialog window = new AccessTypeDialog();
                if (window.ShowDialog() == true)
                {
                    portfolio.AccessType = window.Answer();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                DragDropCanceled(state);
                return;
            }
        }
        base.Drop(state);
    }

}
```

My XAML:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5">
            <Label Content="Available portfolios:"></Label>
            <telerik:RadListBox x:Name="AllPortfolios" TextPath="ShortName" AllowDrop="True" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AvailablePortfolioCustomTemplate}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource DraggableListBoxItem}" MaxHeight="200" SelectionMode="Extended" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllPortfolios, Mode=TwoWay}" MinHeight="20" Margin="10" >
                <telerik:RadListBox.DragDropBehavior>
                    <telerik:ListBoxDragDropBehavior/>
                </telerik:RadListBox.DragDropBehavior>
            </telerik:RadListBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5">
            <Label Content="Current portfolios for user:"></Label>
            <telerik:RadListBox x:Name="UserPortfolios" AllowDrop="True" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UserPortfoliosCustomTemplate}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource DraggableListBoxItem}" SelectionMode="Extended" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UserPortfolios, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinHeight="20" Margin="10" MaxHeight="200">
                <telerik:RadListBox.DragDropBehavior>
                    <!--<telerik:ListBoxDragDropBehavior/>-->
                    <meshPermissionsGui:UserPortfolioListBoxDragDropBehavior/>
                </telerik:RadListBox.DragDropBehavior>
            </telerik:RadListBox>
        </StackPanel>
```

When the update button is pressed on the MainWindowViewModel, it triggers the WriteAll command which does this:

```
// Applications

            List<PermissionApplication> appsToDelete = new List<PermissionApplication>();
            List<PermissionApplication> appsToAddOrEdit = new List<PermissionApplication>();

            foreach (
                PermissionApplication permissionApplication in _vm.Model.GetApplicationsForUser(_vm.SelectedUser))
            {
                if (!_vm.UserApplications.Contains(permissionApplication)) // remove ones that were deleted
                    appsToDelete.Add(permissionApplication);
            }
            foreach (PermissionApplication permissionApplication in _vm.UserApplications) // add or edit new ones
            {
                appsToAddOrEdit.Add(permissionApplication);
            }


            _vm.Model.AddOrEditUserApplications(appsToAddOrEdit, _vm.SelectedUser);
            _vm.Model.DeleteUserApplications(appsToDelete, _vm.SelectedUser);

            // end applications
            // Groups
            List<Group> groupsToDelete = new List<Group>();
            List<Group> groupsToAddOrEdit = new List<Group>();

            foreach (Group g in _vm.Model.GetGroupsForUser(_vm.SelectedUser))
            {
                if (!_vm.UserGroups.Contains(g))
                    groupsToDelete.Add(g);
            }

            foreach (Group g in _vm.UserGroups)
            {
                groupsToAddOrEdit.Add(g);
            }

            _vm.Model.AddOrEditUserGroups(groupsToAddOrEdit, _vm.SelectedUser);
            _vm.Model.DeleteUserGroups(groupsToDelete, _vm.SelectedUser);

            //ends groups
            //Portfolios

            List<PermissionPortfolio> portfoliosToDelete = new List<PermissionPortfolio>();
            List<PermissionPortfolio> portfoliosToAddOrEdit = new List<PermissionPortfolio>();

            foreach (PermissionPortfolio portfolio in _vm.Model.GetUserPortfolios(_vm.SelectedUser))
            {
                if (!_vm.UserPortfolios.Contains(portfolio))
                    portfoliosToDelete.Add(portfolio);
            }

            foreach (PermissionPortfolio portfolio in _vm.UserPortfolios)
            {
                portfoliosToAddOrEdit.Add(portfolio);
            }

            _vm.Model.AddOrEditUserPortfolios(portfoliosToAddOrEdit, _vm.SelectedUser);
            _vm.Model.DeleteUserPortfolios(portfoliosToDelete, _vm.SelectedUser);

            // end portfolios
```

When the user drags one into the second box, regardless of the previous state of the target box, it *should* write everything that is in that box. If something is removed that was previously there, it will delete from the database. This whole thing is supposed to be a GUI to manage database permissions.

The count property of the observable collection is always correct. But sometimes the items are incorrect. It may work for the first 5-6 times and then the 7th time it will break. I am completely stumped.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: My full command class in ViewModel:

```
public class WriteAllCommand : ICommand
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel Vm
        {
            get { return _vm; }
            set
            {
                _vm = value; 
                Debugger.Break();
            }
        }


        public WriteAllCommand(MainWindowViewModel vm)
        {
            Vm = vm;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            AppConfiguration.Log.Write(LogLevel.Info, "WriteAll Command Activated");

            // Applications

            List<PermissionApplication> appsToDelete = new List<PermissionApplication>();
            List<PermissionApplication> appsToAddOrEdit = new List<PermissionApplication>();

            foreach (
                PermissionApplication permissionApplication in Vm.Model.GetApplicationsForUser(Vm.SelectedUser))
            {
                if (!Vm.UserApplications.Contains(permissionApplication)) // remove ones that were deleted
                    appsToDelete.Add(permissionApplication);
            }
            foreach (PermissionApplication permissionApplication in Vm.UserApplications) // add or edit new ones
            {
                appsToAddOrEdit.Add(permissionApplication);
            }


            Vm.Model.AddOrEditUserApplications(appsToAddOrEdit, Vm.SelectedUser);
            Vm.Model.DeleteUserApplications(appsToDelete, Vm.SelectedUser);

            // end applications
            // Groups
            List<Group> groupsToDelete = new List<Group>();
            List<Group> groupsToAddOrEdit = new List<Group>();

            foreach (Group g in Vm.Model.GetGroupsForUser(Vm.SelectedUser))
            {
                if (!Vm.UserGroups.Contains(g))
                    groupsToDelete.Add(g);
            }

            foreach (Group g in Vm.UserGroups)
            {
                groupsToAddOrEdit.Add(g);
            }

            Vm.Model.AddOrEditUserGroups(groupsToAddOrEdit, Vm.SelectedUser);
            Vm.Model.DeleteUserGroups(groupsToDelete, Vm.SelectedUser);

            //ends groups
            //Portfolios

            List<PermissionPortfolio> portfoliosToDelete = new List<PermissionPortfolio>();
            List<PermissionPortfolio> portfoliosToAddOrEdit = new List<PermissionPortfolio>();

            foreach (PermissionPortfolio portfolio in Vm.Model.GetUserPortfolios(Vm.SelectedUser))
            {
                if (!Vm.UserPortfolios.Contains(portfolio))
                    portfoliosToDelete.Add(portfolio);
            }

            foreach (PermissionPortfolio portfolio in Vm.UserPortfolios)
            {
                portfoliosToAddOrEdit.Add(portfolio);
            }

            Vm.Model.AddOrEditUserPortfolios(portfoliosToAddOrEdit, Vm.SelectedUser);
            Vm.Model.DeleteUserPortfolios(portfoliosToDelete, Vm.SelectedUser);

            // end portfolios


            Vm.Refresh.Execute(null);

        }

        bool _canexecute = true;
        private MainWindowViewModel _vm;
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter) { return _canexecute; }
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged { add { } remove { } }
    }
```

The Binding debug when I call the command. This is when it fails:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=58169988): Got
PropertyChanged event from MainWindowViewModel (hash=12012133)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=58169988):   
GetValue at level 0 from MainWindowViewModel (hash=12012133) using RuntimePropertyInfo(UserPortfolios): <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=58169988): TransferValue - got raw value <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=58169988): TransferValue - using final value <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=58169988): Got PropertyChanged event from MainWindowViewModel (hash=12012133)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=58169988): GetValue at level 0 from MainWindowViewModel (hash=12012133) using RuntimePropertyInfo(UserPortfolios): ObservableCollection`1 (hash=33513495 Count=0)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=58169988): TransferValue - got raw value ObservableCollection`1 (hash=33513495 Count=0)
System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[MeshPermissionsGUI.PermissionPortfolio]' BindingExpression:Path=UserPortfolios; DataItem='MainWindowViewModel' (HashCode=12012133); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Warning: 87 : BindingExpression (hash=58169988): TransferValue - value ObservableCollection`1 (hash=33513495 Count=0) is not valid for target
System.Windows.Data Warning: 88 : BindingExpression (hash=58169988): TransferValue - using fallback/default value ''
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=58169988):     TransferValue - using final value ''
```

Ignore the errors in that. It's just me binding that to a textbox in the GUI to get this data. What troubles me is that it is actually getting the wrong number of items.

Comment: Your code example is far too complicated, and yet is also incomplete. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: everytime you are using OnPropertyChanged(); - should you be telling the function what property to notify of change?

public string SystemId
    {
        get { return _systemId; }
        set
        {
            _systemId = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("SystemId");
        }
    }

Comment: ReSharper makes an implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged that supposedly does this for you. What really makes no sense here is that it will work 80% of the time, but occasionally the bindings won't update. I've even tried breaking the MVVM paradigm and manually doing the update in the view but still it will not work.

Comment: Grab Snoop.  Use it at runtime to examine your bindings.  Might help.

Comment: I've got snoop. Pretty cool. There are no errors in my bindings. What troubles me is that shouldn't my ViewModel's collections be changed when I add / remove to my bound collections, before I press any commit button? Currently it only changes when I press the commit button.

Comment: I fixed it. I was triggering a 'refresh' command before this one which effectively locally undid my changes that I wanted to commit. Snoop helped me and showed me that there were two PropertyChanged evnets.